# Sanitizing Output data

Tags: php, strip-tags

I'm using PDO with prepared statements in my code and I would like to know how to better output my data because I'm also using a WYSIWYG editor.
Using strip_tags, htmlentities or htmlspecialchars are not displaying text styles properly.

Here is the code to input data to the database:

```
$sql    = "INSERT INTO posts(post_title, post_content, post_author, post_category, post_tags, post_image)";
                $sql   .= "VALUES(:title, :content, :author, :category, :tags, :image)";
                $stmt   = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
                $result = $stmt->execute([
                    ':title'    => $postTitle,
                    ':content'  => $postContent,
                    ':author'   => $postAuthor,
                    ':category' => $postCategory,
                    ':tags'     => $postTags,
                    ':image'    => $imageFullName
                ]);
```

Comment: What does output have to do with PDO? Your only showing us the insertion code. How do you output it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Comment: to output I'm using htmlentities:<p><?php echo htmlentities($newsSlideExerpt); ?></p>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This built-in functionality you are requesting will be difficult to get. They are many work arounds

1.) you can use external library like like **htmlpurifier**
http://htmlpurifier.org/

**2.) use of strip_tags()**

you can use  `strip_tags()` to allow certain tags tob passed while stripping out other html dangerous tags

Eg to allow only `<h1> and <b>` while stripping out other tags you can do this

```
$text_strip = '<h1>Am nancy.</h1><div>hhhh</div> <b>Mooree</b> <a href="">remove me</a>';
// Allow only <h1> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text_strip , '<h1><b>');
```

see list of data filtering method available
[data filtering: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)

**3.) use of FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING()**

You can also use `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING()` to filter out dangerous text inputs

```
echo filter_var ($text_text, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

see list of all available sanitization methods
[sanitization: https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

**An Updates**

one more thing. You can still be vulnerable to sql injection attack even if you are using pdo. This because the pdo performs sanitization by emulation of deprecated mysql_real_escape_string() function. you will need to force pdo to disable emulation and use direct prepared statements. i will update my answer

To resolve this issue see code below for database connections. charset is set to **utf8**

```
$db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8', 
    'root', // username
        'root123' // password
);

//Disable Emulates pdo and thus forces PDO to use real prepared statement.
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

with this above you are 100% safe against all sorts of sql injection attack. give me a shout on the comment if you appreciate this

Comment: Very Useful. I tried to allow some tags and it's worked.

Comment: one more thing. You can still be vulnerable to sql injection attack even if you are using pdo. This because the pdo performs sanitization by emulation of  deprecated mysql_real_escape_string() function. you will need to force pdo to disable emulation and use direct prepared statements. i will update my answer

Comment: see updated answer for more info on sql injection on pdo @Pitshou

Comment: This is how I connect with pdo: is this safe? PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
         PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE  => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION @Nancy Mooreen

Comment: in production, you can just comment out or  this line in the code if you like and you will be okay $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::EXCEPTION. You can change $db variable to any variable of your choice. you will be okay.